# Lectura de dos enteros con getLine >>=

Tags: haskell

¿Cómo hago para leer dos números desde un inputbox en Haskell online con getLine >>=

```
g::Float -> Float -> Float
g n t = 2 - (n*t**2+3))


main = getLine >>= (\n -> putStrLn(show (g (read n :: String -> Float))))
             g >>= (\t -> putStrLn(show (g (read t :: String -> Float))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Es más cómodo usar el *bloque do* que escribir la operación en función del operador bind `>>=` como parece que intentas hacer.

Así mismo, aprovéchate de la capacidad del compilador para elegir el tipo de la operación polimórfica como con las usadas para leer o escribir en cónsola.

Creo que buscas algo así:

```
g :: Float -> Float -> Float
g n t = 2 - (n*t**2+3)

main :: IO ()
main =
  do
    x <- getLine
    y <- getLine
    print $ g (read x) (read y)
```

Tanto `x` como `y` son `Strings`. Como al invocar la función `g` se esperan dos `Floats`, el compilador sabe que tiene que usar la función `read` de la instancia de la clase `Read Float`.

**Nota**: no sé qué *haskell online* estás usando, ni qué es el *inputbox*.

**Editado**: si lo que quieres es mostrar el resultado junto un aviso:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  do
    x <- getLine
    y <- getLine
    putStr "El resultado es "
    print $ g (read x) (read y)
```

Si no es suficiente, puedes convertir el resultado a una `String` con la función `show`

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  do
    x <- getLine
    y <- getLine
    let res = g (read x) (read y)
    putStrLn ("El resultado es " ++ show res)
```

Comment: Inputbox le llamo a la caja de texto en la cual el usuario escribe la entrada de datos y el sitio para ejecutar códigos de manera online es este http://rextester.com/l/haskell_online_compiler

Comment: Me gustaría añadir un cartel en la línea del print, pero tira error y no sé como corregirlo. Algo así putStrLn ("El resultado es ") ++ print $ f (read n) para que el cartel y el resultado queden en una misma línea.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para añadir estos detalles...